# Do I need to add .apply() to write preference value when I use androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1 with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

The function of Code A is to read and write preference value using `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1` with kotlin. I don't know if it's correct, could you tell me?

And more, I think I can remove `.apply()` when I use `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1` just like Code B, is it correct?

**Code A**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager

class PreferenceTool<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String, private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {      
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {              //I change from Any to Any?
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)?:default
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }
        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
...
class PreferenceTool<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String, private val default: T) {
   ...

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) from Kotlin standard library makes its argument accessible as receiver. That's it, nothing else. It has no notion of Android `SharedPreference` and its `Editor` or that any changes to it have to be commited. So this...

> I think I can remove `.apply()` [...] just like Code B, is it correct?

...is incorrect. Here's what you can do:

a) Call `SharedPreference.Editor.apply()` at the end, like in your code example A.

b) Use `SharedPreference.edit {}` extension function from AndroidX Core KTX, which gives  you an `Editor` as receiver and calls `apply` or `commit` at the end.

```
private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = prefs.edit(commit = false) {
    when (value) {
        is Long -> putLong(name, value)
        is String -> putString(name, value)
        is Int -> putInt(name, value)
        is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
        is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
    }
}
```

See [SharedPreferences.kt - Source](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:core/core-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/SharedPreferences.kt;l=39;drc=baab6d3bde8d6ca25968b1b60088ac1f8db5afbc).

c) Refactor, create a `SharedPreference.Editor.put` fluent-style extension function, then call it:

```
private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) {
    prefs.edit()
        .put(name, value)
        .apply()
}

private fun SharedPreferences.Editor.put(name: String, value: Any) = apply {
    when (value) {
        is Long -> putLong(name, value)
        is String -> putString(name, value)
        is Int -> putInt(name, value)
        is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
        is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
    }
}
```

Here, [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) also comes from Kotlin standard library. I used it so I didn't have to write

```
                                                                      // vvvvvv this vvvvvv
private fun SharedPreferences.Editor.put(name: String, value: Any): SharedPreferences.Editor {
    when (value) {
        // ...
    }
    return this // <<<<<< and this
}
```

**Choose whichever option will be most understandable to you when you see your code half a year in the future.**

Comment: Option (c) doesn't need generics, does it? It doesn't return a type or restrict the type.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, if I make `value: Any`, that should be fine.